# Copy element background color to clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to copy an element's background color on-click. I'm getting the computed rgb value, but what I need copied to the clipboard is **var(--primary)**

https://codepen.io/avviodigital/pen/WNZNOVb

```js
const copyToClipboard = str => {
    const el = document.createElement('textarea');
    el.value = str;
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    el.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(el);
};

jQuery('.card').click( function () {
    color = $(this).css( "background-color" );
    copyToClipboard(color);
});
```

```css
body {
  --primary: #7306f9;
}

.card {
  background-color: var(--primary);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="card"></div>
```

Comment: You can only get the rgb value regardless of how the value is set in css rules

Comment: You can use the function to convert rgb to hex. Please refer https://codepen.io/camponogara/pen/EmXmgy